# Does Character Varying Array apply precision restrictions to each element within the array?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to implement a character varying array in this format:

- `<column-name> character varying(7)[ ]`

I wanted to create an array of character varying that still upholds the 7 character precision.

Will Postgres do that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PostgreSQL will do that as you wish, as you can easily verify:

```
CREATE TABLE vararr(
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   v varchar(7)[]
);

INSERT INTO vararr VALUES (1, '{abc,def,ghi}');

INSERT INTO vararr VALUES (2, '{abcabcabc,def,ghi}');
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(7)
```